# How to add custom identity provider (for example Instagram) in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, identity, azure-ad-b2c

How to add authorization through third-party services (for example Instagram or Vk) which are not in the list of Azure AD B2C identity providers?

Answer (score 1):

If the identity provider supports OpenID Connect, you can use the generic OpenID Connect identity provider.
Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp

If they do not, then you need to create a custom policy using the Identity Experience Framework.
There you can define an identity provider which uses various protocols,
but it is quite an advanced scenario.
Custom policy learning curve is quite steep.
Docs for them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom?tabs=applications

Comment: And where can I find `.well-known\openid-configuration` file needed to configure provider?

Comment: Their documentation should mention that. It's essentially the Authority + ".well-known/openid-configuration".

Comment: but there is nothing written about it